# Getting rid of the blue focus rectangle on input boxes in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, macos

I'm running Mac OS so I can't really tell if this effect is presented on windows machines or not, so I apologize if this effect is not seen for you.

Input and TextFields seem to have a blue rectangle when focused, atleast on Firefox and Chrome on a Mac.  I have a custom focus effect on a site, and I'm wondering if I can avoid having this default selection behavior show.  Google avoids it on their site.  I went as far as to get the 'in-effect' CSS style for Google's input box, apply that to my css object.  However, it still shows the blue rectangle.  I'm not exactly sure what kind of voodoo google is doing, but it seems to me that it's neither HTML or CSS attributes.  Anyone know how to avoid this effect?  Thanks!

Answer (score 137, accepted):

It is in fact a CSS attribute. This will hide that glowing effect:

```
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I've used this before, too.. Doh.  Thanks alot..  (Works brilliantly)

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a browser usability feature. Users, especially keyboard-centric users, like knowing where the focus is before typing. If you remove this behavior, consider providing other ways to indicate focus for the user.

Comment: To add to what Doug said, this is not just a usability feature, its an accessibility feature. See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/a11y.html#keyboard  It's a little annoying that on OSX the outline is so bold.

Comment: For certain non-form elements, the outline displays even when it's not useful or necessary for accessibility (block elements, dragged elements, etc)—this style works great to prevent it, and it has no drawback when it's truly not a form element.

Comment: @BoltClock, sometimes i was having this issue because of box-shadow

Comment: What browser is it not working on? Would be useful in solving your issue

Comment: This is useful for emulating native OS behavior when combined with some JS for onClick. For example, accessibility aside, Mac OS X doesn't highlight popup menus in blue whenever you click them. And depending on the app, focus rects may not even be used with certain text fields, which is up to the developer. Though I agree it should be used with care, especially with pages used by a lot of different people.

Comment: What if i have a tabindex applied to non focus-able elements such as span and div. Using `*:focus { outline: none; }` works, however am not sure if that is the correct way. Please confirm.