# In JavaFx, how to control focus of a custom control?

Tags: javafx, focus, javafx-8

Suppose a JavaFX `CustomControl` node that contains, say, two `TextField`s.

If any of these `TextField`s has the focus, then `CustomControl.isFocused()` should return `true`. If none of them has focus, then `CustomControl.isFocused()` should return `false`.

How do I do that?

Comment: See [*Focus Listener for JavaFX Nodes*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21798183/230513).

Comment: @trashgod That post is about attaching focus listeners. That's not my problem. I have a CustomControl which is COMPOSED by these two text-fields. Think about a tree that is to be considered focused if any of its leaves is focused.

Comment: I believe you can use delegation, as suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `CustomControl` uses *composition*, you can *delegate* to the focus properties of each `TextField`. Given two instances,

```
private final TextField tf1 = new TextField("One");
private final TextField tf2 = new TextField("Two");
```

The implementation of an instance method `isFocused()` is then straightforward:

```
private boolean isFocused() {
    return tf1.isFocused() | tf2.isFocused();
}
```

Add focus listeners as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37539400/230513) to see the effect.

```
tf1.focusedProperty().addListener((Observable o) -> {
    System.out.println(isFocused());
});
tf2.focusedProperty().addListener((Observable o) -> {
    System.out.println(isFocused());
});
```

> This can't be done. The whole problem is that `isFocused()` is `final` in `Node`.

It seems you wanted to override `isFocused()` in `CustomControl`, but that is not possible for a `final` method and it would violate the notion of a single component having focus. As `CustomControl` is a composite, you'll need to manage focus internally. You may want to use a custom `FocusModel` as seen in [`ListView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html).

Comment: This can't be done. The whole problem is that  `isFocused()` is `final` in `Node`.

Comment: Ah, you want to override `isFocused()` in `CustomControl`; more above.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the concept of a FocusModel. I couldn't find any explanation of what a FocusModel is and how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: It's just a way to manage focus among an arbitrary number of items; here's the `ListView` [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/scene/control/ListView.java#ListView.ListViewFocusModel); IMO, your `CustomControl` should return the default, `false`, as it is not focusable _per se_. What class do you expect to use the result of `isFocused()`, above, or the `aggregatedFocusProperty`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45511677/230513)?

Comment: I have experience with the way focus works with Web Components, where if an internal element has focus, the containing component as a whole is considered to have focus. I assumed that Javafx focus implementation would have the same principle, but it seems that's not the case.

Comment: Ah, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32575793/230513). This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31909941/230513) illustrates the default traversal policy; note how some controls change appearance when focused for input, while others do not; see [`Node::requestFocus`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#requestFocus--) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Try one line solution:

```
public BooleanBinding aggregatedFocusProperty() {
   return Bindings.or(field1.focusedProperty(), field2.focusedProperty());
}
```

Now on a client side you may listen this aggregated focus property.